# Frameworks for targetting multiple environments

Tags: technology, economics, frameworks

What should drive the decision behind doing development upon one or more than one framework?

For instance, an ERP is (mostly) run on a Windows station. It leverages full access to device's resources, like printers, barcode readers, fingerprint readers and the like. It's usually more responsive and easier do develop with.

That being said, some parts of it must be accessed exclusively in self-service mode, by enterprise's customers, suppliers and partners. This could be accomplished with smartphones, tablets, or even desktops running a web browser.

What are the economics behind that? Should two team be kept, each one doing work upon its own framework? Or the most permissive framework should be chosen? Should I care something other than HTML technologies? Should I consider native technology for each device?

Comment: This is fairly localized and in general this type of problem is solved by money or the lack thereof. Do you have money to hire a separate team? Do you have money to support 2 streams? Obviously an environment which allows sharing a code base across platforms is beneficial but there is so much more then that to consider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you architect it in such a way that you offload most of the work and common components to a server somewhere and offer solid webservices that your clients connect to.  That way, the desktop app can take full advantage of the client mache, and the mobile devices can take advantage of a different UI/Feature set that makes sense there, but the code base stays consistent through your service layer, which stays common.